# How to perform Integration Test on Queues

Tags: java, testing, integration-testing, ibm-mq

How do I write Integration Tests for my Java Services, which do actions against a real Queue. My classes do connections, deletes etc. ?

Is there any way to test these services without performing actions against the productive Queues?

I searched the net for while but didn't come up with a solution.

Comment: You can setup test queues to be used for integration tests, you don't test against prod stuff. Or you mock the queues and write unit tests.

Comment: Install a developer edition queue manager?

Comment: If you have Docker installed, you can use [Testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/) and start an [IBM MQ container](https://github.com/ibm-messaging/mq-container).

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple approaches that I can think of regarding writing Integration tests against queues.

- Setup test queues and then have your code post messages to it which will return a correlationId when successful. Then you have a test consumer within the test consume it using correlationId. This will help you assert specific messages vs getting a random message. We use this mechanism for tests as well as for synthetic monitoring.
- If you are using the REST API provided by IBM MQ beginning V 9.X to interact with queues, you can use a mock service like http://www.mbtest.org/ to mock out the target endpoint and then that can be used within an Integration test.
- Alternatively you can use the combination of the about two options by using the API to actually post and consumer messages using the correlationId
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=messagingqmgrqmgrnamequeuequeuenamemessage-post
- https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=messagingqmgrqmgrnamequeuequeuenamemessage-get